# Change dates in an xml file to today's date

Tags: xml, powershell

I am working on automating one of our processes by importing and exporting data through Web services. the web service call reads through the parameters that I have in an XML File. The data export has to be performed on a daily basis. so I am trying to create a script that would modify the start date and enddate section in my XML file to today's date. 
Could anyone recommend any efficient ways to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:vertexinc:oseries:taxdata:datamanagement:8:0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:RunTaxDataExportRequest>
         <urn:ExportFileName>taxdataexport.txt</urn:ExportFileName>
     <urn:StartDate>2019-06-06</urn:StartDate>
     <urn:EndDate>2019-06-07</urn:EndDate>
         <FieldDelimiter>TILDE</FieldDelimiter>
         <urn:RecordType>CERTIFICATE</urn:RecordType>
         <urn:Login>
            <urn:UserName>yyyy</urn:UserName>
            <urn:Password>xxx</urn:Password>
         </urn:Login>
      </urn:RunTaxDataExportRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: A useful search expression to use at the top of this page would be `[powershell][xml] edit xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with your xml, you will need to convert it to an xml object first. Then it should be pretty straight forward to mess with it.

The following should accomplish what you are attempting to do.

Example:

```
#XML example
$xmlExample = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:vertexinc:oseries:taxdata:datamanagement:8:0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:RunTaxDataExportRequest>
         <urn:ExportFileName>taxdataexport.txt</urn:ExportFileName>
     <urn:StartDate>2019-06-06</urn:StartDate>
     <urn:EndDate>2019-06-07</urn:EndDate>
         <FieldDelimiter>TILDE</FieldDelimiter>
         <urn:RecordType>CERTIFICATE</urn:RecordType>
         <urn:Login>
            <urn:UserName>yyyy</urn:UserName>
            <urn:Password>xxx</urn:Password>
         </urn:Login>
      </urn:RunTaxDataExportRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

#convert example to xml object
[xml]$xml = $xmlExample

#Change Start / End to today
$xml.Envelope.Body.RunTaxDataExportRequest.StartDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$xml.Envelope.Body.RunTaxDataExportRequest.EndDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

#Display Results --- or do whatever with it
$xml.Envelope.Body.RunTaxDataExportRequest
```

Comment: But my XML code is in a file called DataExport.xml. I need the powershell script to modify the dates inside the file.

Comment: Thank you, your proposed solution worked perfectly. I just just added the file read and write to it.